# Can we use a counter variable inside to form another variable so I can access it's value?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance-testing, test-script

I have a Regex Extractor that retrieves following values,

[image]

With this, i'm trying to retrieve all such values, `orderId_1_g1=SGSM10820`, `orderId_2_g1=SGSM10821`, `orderId_3_g1=SGSM10822`, and pass them in a HTTP Request that follows as a parameter.

For this, I've put them in a `Loop Controller` and a `Counter`. Now, when using `${orderId_${counter}_g1}` to get the value; I don't actually receive the value instead get the variable `${orderId_${counter}_g1}` as it is.

NOTE: I'm trying to use a counter to form name of another variable. Is it possible or there's some other efficient way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate JMeter Variables this way, in order to evaluate nested JMeter Variables you need to use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like:

```
${__V(orderId_${counter}_g1)}
```

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is an array to store these values in:

e.g.

```java
String[] orderId= new String[100];
```

Then you can either manually set them all

```java
orderId[1]="SGSM10820";
orderId[2]="SGSM10820";
// and so on
```

Or stick it all in a loop to do a common thing for each entry

```java
for (int n = 0; n < orderId.length; n++) {
    // do something for all entries in array
    //orderId[n] is currently selected

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution after tinkering with the controllers for a while.

Instead of using a `Loop Controller` we can use `ForEach Controller` and not worry about the complex expression that the `RegEx Extractor` returns as the latter controller handle that wisely. Use the value in the `output variable` set into the loop controller to get the desired value.